# data transfer from one activity to another activity on button click event

Tags: android

i try to transfer data from one activity to another but i can't achieve it.. can any one assit me.. kindly assit with example... thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` to transfer you data from `Activity` to another. Check out [Android Developer | Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [Android Developer | Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 2):

Only primitive data types like string, integers etc can be passed. Also you can pass ArrayList etc. Object cannot be passed. Following are a few lines of code to explain:

From the activity you want to send data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LABEL", <data>);
```

In the new activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
data = bundle.getInt("LABEL");
```

Comment: thanks amiekuser....i need to transfer it from child activity to parent activity..so, i cant exception and forced closed while initialize the parent activity...