# How to pass data between activity through Html hyperlink in Android TextView?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `TextView` that is Hyperlinked. The code like this

```
textPaymentMethod.setText(
Html.fromHtml("<b><a href=\"shippinginfo-activity://shippinginfo\">Add Payment Method</a></b>"));
tvPaymentMethod.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

When a user `Click` on `AddPayment` method it will go Another `Activity` like `ActivityX`. But my problem is, I want to pass some data from current `Activity`to `ActivityX`. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass data using an object. Else you can use Put Extra.
Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967740/transfer-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity

Comment: Can you show me how to pass data using PutExtra.

Comment: Check Kameswaris answer below. It deals with PutExtra.

Comment: Sorry, I don't need this. Actually it is not the perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your need then?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452944/1344221). Look in the comments which detail a method for passing data to another activity through the use of strings.

Comment: Although it would have been good to popular this with the answer instead of the link to the answer. This link did help me though so +1

Answer (score 0):

In order to move from one activity to other write the following code

```
//move to next activity
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
//pass your data here
intent.putExtra("data", <your data value>);
//start Activity
startIntent(intent);
In Activity3, to get your edit text value do the following.

//get your data value here which is passed in FirstActivity
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

The variable "data" is the final output which you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your current Activity

```
Intent activity= new Intent(Activity.this, ActivityX.class);

activity.putExtra("key", <value>);

startIntent(activity);
```

ActivityX: in OnCreate()

```
Intent value = getIntent();
String str_value= (String) usrid.getSerializableExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with Phil's help and I read this answer here: [handle textview link click in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app/3452944#3452944)

Add the following intent-filter to the manifest activity you want to hyperlink to, of course replacing the scheme with your own scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="com.package.name" />  
</intent-filter>
```

Now, create your hyperlink with the scheme and put it within your string file. My link has the same android:scheme as the intent-filter and it is appended by an actual external link to a site on the internet. In my case, I want to click on the link, it must open another activity and the other activity has a webview which would display the webpage. This prevents the user from seeing the url of the webpage I have directed them to on the phone.

```
<string name="signing_in">&lt;a href=&quot;com.package.name://http://your_real_external_link_goes_here&quot;&gt;Privacy Policy&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

In my activity with the webview, I say:

```
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data != null) {
        url = data.toString().substring(19 , data.toString().length());
        Log.e("url", url);
    }
```

We substring out the part that says: `com.package.name://` which in total is 19 character and you the remaining portion would be my url which I can then use to load my webpage without the url being displayed.