# How to transfer data from one activity to another in android

Tags: java, android

It might sound simple but I can't make it working.  I have two activities. Which first one is a form, and second one is showing data from a JSON file based on values entered in the first activity.

So I am trying to make a simple version of it. I have a EditText, and a button, so when they press the button, whatever was in the EditText will be in the TextView of the next activity.

Here is my code so far:
**Main Activity**

```
static TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void transferIT(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public static String getText(){
    String data = (String) textView.getText();
    return data;
}
```

**Main XML**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Text to transfer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Transfer it"
    android:onClick="transferIT" />
```

**Second Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();


    TextView enteredValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    enteredValue.setText(MainActivity.getText());

}
```

**Second XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />
```

In this way I made a method for the data of the EditText and in the other activity I call it to get access to it. Currently when I press the button it stops working. So what is your solution for having the data of the form in other activity ?

Comment: @user3026034 I've spotted that you store textView in a static field. You should not do that or you'll cause a memory leak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer data from one Activity to Another Activity Using Intents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967740/transfer-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-using-intents)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the first activity you should put the extra argument to intent like this:

```
// I assume Page.class is your second activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page.class); 
intent.putExtra("arg", getText()); // getText() SHOULD NOT be static!!!
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the second activity, you retrieve the argument like this:

```
String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("arg");
enteredValue.setText(passedArg);
```

It's also good to store the `arg` String in MainActivity as constant and always refer to it in other places.

```
public static final String ARG_FROM_MAIN = "arg";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
 static TextView textView;
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

to

```
 EditText ed1; 
 ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Coz you have

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1" // it is edittext not textview
```

Then

```
public void transferIT(View view){
String value = ed1.getText().toString()
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page.class);
intent.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in onCreate of second activity

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Answer (score 3):

You send the data in the intent when you call the second activity. This is pretty fundamental stuff. I suggest you read up on Intents and Parcelable concepts in Android and Serialization in Java that are all related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

we are sending data from one activity to another where the first activity is mainActivity and another is `otherActivity`
for `mainActivity`

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
in.putExtra("name", etname.getText().toString());
in.putExtra("job", etjob.getText().toString());
in.putExtra("sal", etsal.getText().toString());    
startActivity(in);
```

for otherActivity

```
Intent in = getIntent();
tv.setText(in.getStringExtra("name")+"\n"+in.getStringExtra("job")+" "+in.getStringExtra("sal"));
```

Answer (score 2):

#### We are sending data from MainActivity to another Activity

MainActivity code that is sending data to another activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText t1, t2, t3;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.move);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String name = t1.getText().toString();
                String email = t2.getText().toString();
                String edu = t3.getText().toString();
                if (name.equals("") || email.equals("") || edu.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the form", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("fname", name);
                    /*putExtra method take two parameter,first is key  and second is value. By using key, we retrieve data
                     */

                    intent.putExtra("femail", email);
                    intent.putExtra("fedu", edu);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Receiving activity code whose name is Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        //We create  object of Bundle class that help to get data from MainActivity and used its  getString method

        Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = bn.getString("fname");
        String email = bn.getString("femail");
        String edu = bn.getString("fedu");
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(name));
        textView2.setText(String.valueOf(email));
        textView3.setText(String.valueOf(edu));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can implement this using the beneath possible ways,

1. SharedPrefrence
2. Instance (getter , setter method)
3. Constant method

**1. SharedPrefrence**

```
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs"; 

    // set the sharedprefrence
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("MasterAgilData", RestoreMasterData);
    editor.commit();

    // restore the sharedprefrence
    String RestoreMasterData1 = sharedpreferences.getString("MasterAgilData", "");
```

**2. Instance**

```
public class instance {

public static AgilDataList StoreAgilDataList;

public static AgilDataList getStoremasterDataList() {
    return StoreAgilDataList;
}

public static void setStoremasterDataList(AgilDataList storemasterDataList) 
{
    StoreAgilDataList = storemasterDataList;
}
}
```

**3. Constant method** (static variable)

```
public class First_Activity extends Activity {
 public static String USER_FORMATED_NUMBER = null;

 USER_FORMATED_NUMBER="Data you want to pass"; 
}

public class Second_Activity extends Activity {
 String data=First_Activity.USER_FORMATED_NUMBER; 
}
```