# Why does this throw a 'null object reference' error?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a string from another activity to this one and then send it into an array and then into a listview. whenever i run this i get "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference"
it seems like the error has something to do with the fourth line with the 'extras' bundle but how is that a null object reference i defined it right there no?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    switch(requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
            String title = extras.getString(add.TITLE);
            String password = extras.getString(add.PASSWORD);
            adapter.add(title);
            break;
    }


}
```

Here's where the 'PASSWORD' and 'TITLE' variables are defined in the other Activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText titleBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    TITLE = titleBox.getText().toString();

    EditText passBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwdText);
    String pass = passBox.getText().toString();

    EditText confBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    String conf = confBox.getText().toString();

    if (pass.equals(conf)) {

        PASSWORD = pass;
        this.finish();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass data from one activity to another using a Bundle, the data is received inside `onCreate()` method of the second activity not inside `onActivityResult()` unless you've specifically implemented that.

Check this answer on how to start another activity and how to pass data to another activity : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170125/1239966