# how to set response of an activity to other activity? ex: login response to profile page

Tags: android, performance, request, login-control

how to set response of an activity to other activity ex login response to profile page by click on the button.
Where i want to set all the response over profile page activity.
i want this data after login
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaV8u.png)

to set here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVe4z.png)

Comment: could you please send the links so that i can check @nilesh Rathod

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169993/how-to-transfer-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android