# How to send data from one activity to an already existing activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have two activities for a drawing app I am making, let's call them A and B.
Activity A is the canvas the user draws on, and thus will always be active so it does not lose its state. Activity B is activated when a button on A is pressed and opens a menu to change the drawing colour. I want to be able to click a button on B and have it send the colour value of the button in B to the existing A to update the colour, but haven't found any way to be able to do that.

I know it should be done in the onClick for the buttons, but other than that I don't have any clue.

Alternatively, is there a way to save the state of A somewhere and then start a new instance of A and reload it with the same drawings on it but updated drawing colour?

Comment: please check this previously asked question that will help in clearing your concepts.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169993/how-to-transfer-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: Instead of startActivity you should use startActivityForResult. Activity B then puts the chosen color in the result intent and finishes. A can then read  the color from the intent.

Comment: Do you know about handlers in android? Well you have many options: handlers,  maybe callbacks, activity result, shared preferences, view models etc. It depends what kind of data you deal with. If it is an `int` type color value, it is relatively easier than handling complex object values.

Comment: How about put the data in a singleton model class and access it via Activity, Service or other utility. This is the most common way to do so in the scope of a single application.

Comment: I am sure that there will be someone mentioned that this is not so good comparing to pass an Intent from one activity to another. But I only use intent when I need to call from App A to App B.