# How to Exchange Text between Screens in android app

Tags: java, android

While Developing of an Intent Android application. I want to insert data in main_actvity.java and get the same data in intent_activity.java(I want to insert data in activity_main.xml and get data in intent_test.xml)

Example: I want to login(With username and password) and display my username in next screen(after logging).

Comment: You should try it yourself & search out first before asking questions here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4967833/4489552

Comment: there are several options for this. tell me if you need to save the data even after the activity is killed .?

Answer (score 1):

**Using INTENT we can pass data from one Activity to another activity.**

use INTENT for first Activity....

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Next.class);//`this` is your class context and `Next.class` is another activity. 
i.putExtra("username",username.getText());
i.putExtra("password",password.getText());
startActivity(i);
```

use second Activity;

```
String username=getIntent().getStringExtra("username"),password=getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
```

Enjoy coding.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent as @Sushil suggested. Another way i can suggest is use of **SharedPreferences**. Google some good tutorials on using SharedPreferences for easy storage of app data.