# I'm trying to get variable from onCreate() and use in other class

Tags: java, android, xml

```
public TextView textView;
public TextView textView1;

//Bank bank = new Bank();

// public int myNumber1;
//public int myNumbe


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);

    int element = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
    final int element1 = element * 3;

    textView1.setText("" + element1);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bank.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Which variable? Which other class? A little more context would be helpful

Comment: I think your question not proper, please added some text with a code for better understanding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967833/8200290

Answer (score 0):

First - as others have said in comments, please put more information so others can help you.
Looks like these are the controls/variables you are trying to share with other classes

```
public TextView textView;
public TextView textView1;
int element;
```

You can pass these into another class via

- Constructor arguments
- Methods
- Public fields (i personally don't prefer this)