# Android TextView.SetText NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, textview, settext

I have two activities, activity one has buttons that refer to activity two and methods in it. I'm trying to use TextView.SetText to put something on the screen but keep getting NullPointerException.

Activity 2:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
TextView textview ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textview );
    spill("Some text");

}
public void spill(String s){
    textview.setText(s);
}

public void methodCalledFromActivityOne(){
    System.out.println("Works");
    spill("Why Doesn't this work?");
}
```

XML has this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    tools:context=".SomeActivity" />
```

I'm new to Android and will REALLY appreciate all/any help.

EDIT: The name of the XML is fine, the error only occurs when I press button 1 in activity 1 which calls methodCalledFromActivityOne(). 
This is what I get from LogCat:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.findViewById at data.storage.SomeActivity.spill at data.storage.SomeActivity.methodCalledFromActivityOne
at data.storage.ActivityOne.button1clicked

Comment: When you get an error, please provide us with some more info like at what rule the error occurs... I am guessing that your xml file has the wrong name, the name of your xml file should be: some_activity.xml in this case!

Comment: When this method methodCalledFromActivityOne is called ?

Comment: If you call 
public void spill(String s){
    textview.setText(s);
} 
method from first activity you will get NullPointerException as this TextView is not present in that activity's layout. Please post code of first activity and its xml layout

Comment: Trickster, I added the TextView in activity one and it cleared the NullPointer but the other stuff remained. I guess using the Intent is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

textview in activity 2 will be initialized only when onCreate() is called. And onCreate() of activity 2 will be called only when this activity comes into the phone view. You cannot set the values of views of another activity from your current activity. It is a bad idea. 
If you want the values to get to activity 2, then send those in an intent.

Comment: Go to http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html and scroll down to section 1.4

Comment: or goto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872856/data-transfer-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-on-button-click-event

Comment: Thanks, what I'm trying to do but failing is to just have a set of buttons that all put different texts on a new empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling  `methodCalledFromActivityOne()`  method from another activity make sure you've created `TextView` property at that activity also. Otherwise it'll not work.